# Desinstalar Visual Studio Community 2015. (Errores durante la instalación)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Tuvé problemas al instalar VS con errores, ahora intento desinstalar para reinstalar todo y verificar bien los errores generados anteriormente. Pero no encuentró como desinstalar todo.
¿Como se puede hacer?

Aquí los errores generados, durante instalación...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

@ArmandoArellan, para realizar una desinstalación forzada accede a la carpeta `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\` realizas la búsqueda de `vs_community.exe` y 
obtienes la información de la carpeta donde se encuenta (En mi caso tengo instalado dicha versión):

[image: Resultado de la búsqueda]

En `cmd` te ubica en la carpeta y ejecutas el comando: `vs_community.exe /uninstall /force`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD. el guid varía para cada instalación.

Comment: @ArmandoArellano pensé que querías instalar VS 2015 Community, al final lo vas a desinstalar. ¿No pudiste reinstalarlo?

Comment: si asi es, pero primero lo debo des instalar ¿cierto?

Comment: @ArmandoArrellano solo sobreescribir la anterior instalación y para hacerlo es nuevamente intentar instalarlo. En caso te aparezca en Programas del Panel de Control puedes reparar la instalación. La respuesta que puse en caso no haya instalado bien y forzar la desinstalación.

Comment: intentaré, muchas gracias